# cakePHP optional validation for file upload

Tags: validation, cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-1.3

How to make file uploading as optional with validation?
The code below validates even if i didn't selected any file.
I want to check the extension only if i selected the the file.
If i am not selecting any file it should not return any validation error.

```
class Catalog extends AppModel{
    var $name = 'Catalog';
    var $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'rule' => '/^[a-z0-9 ]{0,}$/i',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => 'Invalid Catalog name'
        ),
        'imageupload' => array(
            'rule' => array('extension',array('jpeg','jpg','png','gif')),
            'required' => false,
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => 'Invalid file'
        ),
       );
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you pre-processing the `imageupload` field in the controller in any way?

Comment: @deceze : sorry what do u mean by pre-processing???  
i need to save only the imagename so i assign $this->data['Catalog']['image'] = $this->data['Catalog']['imageupload']['name'];
then only i will call the save

Comment: That's what I mean by pre-processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I assign $this->data['Catalog']['image'] = $this->data['Catalog']['imageupload']['name'];"

So by the time you save your data array, it looks something like this I assume:

```
array(
    'image' => 'foobar',
    'imageupload' => array(
        'name' => 'foobar',
        'size' => 1234567,
        'error' => 0,
        ...
     )
)
```

Which means, the `imageupload` validation rule is trying to work on this data:

```
array(
    'name' => 'foobar',
    'size' => 1234567,
    'error' => 0,
    ...
 )
```

I.e. the value it's trying to validate is an array of stuff, not just a string. And that is unlikely to pass the specified validation rule. It's also probably never "empty".

Either you create a custom validation rule that can handle this array, or you need to do some more processing in the controller before you try to validate it.

Comment: which is the best practice???custom validation or some more processing in controller

Comment: Personally I would tinker with `$this->data` before saving it, although I think a custom rule would be better practise.

Answer (score 1):

**Concept:**

In Controller, before validating, or saving (which does validation automatically by default) check if any file is uploaded. If not uploaded, then unset validator for the file field.

**Sample code:**

Controller

```
// is any image uploaded?
$isNoFileUploaded = ($this->request->data['Model']['field_name']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) ? true : false ;
if ($isNoFileUploaded) {
    $this->Model->validator()->remove('field_name');
}
```

**Notes:**

This solution comes under preprocessing as one of the two alternative approaches (preprocessing in controller, custom validation in model) suggested by [@deceze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3148126/216084)