# CakePHP when using uploadedit validation, save fails

Tags: validation, cakephp, upload

Okay, so I am uploading documents when a user registers on my site, I collect some personal information and save it. Now I have had a bit of a problem, I split up the main registration form into a couple of view, where the user once logged in can now edit certain information, like for example one field called personal_introduction. For some reason this wont save, even though there are no validation errors on the field. Messed around in the model, to try pick up the problem and fount THIS causes the problem:

```
    'document_file' => array(
        'checkuploadedit' =>array(
            'rule' => array('checkUpload', false),
            'message' => 'Please select your document.',            
        ),
        'checkuploadedit' => array(
            'rule' => array('extension', array('doc', 'docx', 'txt', 'rtf')),
            'message' => 'File extentions allowed: .doc .docx .txt .rtf - we do NOT accept pdf format.'
        )
    ),
```

Once I remove this from my model, it saves the data. Now its weird for me that the main registration form gives no problems, and that this view that does not even contain a form input called "document_file" fails the save.

Any ideas...Please!!! Obviously I need to validate the upload.

I tried this: [validation on a input file in cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185603/validation-on-a-input-file-in-cakephp) , thinking that maybe the above code is not correct, still no luck.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Cheers Louis.

Comment: when you save is checkUpload being executed?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by that, and how I can check it please.

Comment: Well checkUpload is a custom validation rule that you created. Chuck a die('here') or something to see if its executed. Then we'll have to look at the contents of $this->request->data and the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

I went on to further investigate the problem, and found the following, which I still cant explain. When submitting views that do not contain the upload form on the same model, it still tries to validate the upload form, I could actually see the value for one as if submitted, even though it was not. so the only solution I got was to go use unset($this->data['user']['document']) for the actions which do not have the document upload form field. Hope this makes sense.