# validate file size / file type cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.4

Hello guys I'm new to cakephp.
I wanted to validate the file before uploading it, I'v seen some people asking about the same thing. But I don't want custom functions. **Here's the example I DONT WANT**
[validation on a input file in cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185603/validation-on-a-input-file-in-cakephp)

**and here's the code that I d prefer , but its not working**

**Model:**

```
class Career extends AppModel 
{
    public $validate = array(
          'file' => array(
                'checktype' => array(
                    'rule' => array('extension',array('pdf','doc','docx')),
                    'message' => 'Please supply a valid file type (PDF OR WORD)',

                ),
                'checksize' =>array(
                        'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '1MB'),
                        'message' => 'File must be less than 1MB',

                ),
            ),
      );
 }
```

I also want to add that the file is not mandatory/must, but if you are going to upload it, it must be *.pdf/.doc/.docx* and less than *1MB*.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do it without implementing custom functions unless you use a plugin built by someone else. If you want to implement it yourself and validate the file before uploading it you will need to use the built in php validation which you can read about here: [File upload post method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

However I suggest using Miles Johnson's incredible Uploader plugin which you can find here:
[Uploader](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader)

With his library you can apply validation like so:

```
public $actsAs = array(
  'Uploader.FileValidation' => array(
       'image' => array(
           'maxWidth' => 100,
           'minHeight' => 100,
           'extension' => array('gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'),
           'type' => 'image',
           'mimeType' => array('image/gif'),
           'filesize' => 5242880,
           'required' => true
       )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use my [FileStorage plugin](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage). It's a complete solution to handling files in your app, completely customizable through event listeners or by extending its models.

However, you can also just [use it's FileUploadValidation behavior](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/blob/master/Model/Behavior/UploadValidatorBehavior.php).

For [Image validation](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/blob/master/Model/ImageStorage.php#L178) see [this method](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/blob/master/Model/ImageStorage.php#L178). It makes use of the Image library which is used here to process images and wrapped in the [Imagine plugin](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-imagine-plugin) that is required if you want to process images (works on the fly, automatically if present).